# Error Tapping a section of code

Tags: python

I have a while statement which works well and I have a whole section of code that asks the user to input how many names they have which will then ask them for a name that amount of times and then each time a name will be entered.

I need the section of the names entered to be error tapped but I don't know how to do it, as I have a while statement and I may need to put another while statement in, although I have error tapped the section for amount of names in numbers.

Also there is code further on with a dictionary and sorts but I need help with the one section of error tapping started at while currentnum part

```
print("Please enter each name when asked without any spaces.") #The program will post this
print("Please enter each of your names individually also.")    #Program will again post this

names = [] #This is the value of names which will be changed depending on the input
currentnum = 0 #Currentnum value is 0

while True:  #While loop as it will revert to the start if question answered incorrectly
        try:
                numofnames = int(input("How many names do you have? "))
        except ValueError: #if the input is not an integer or a whole number it will
                print("Sorry that was not a valid input please retry")
                continue  #it will loop back and ask the question again as it says that the unput was not valid
        else:
                break #If the input is correct then the loop will break and continue to the next section of the program

while currentnum < numofnames: #This means that while currentnum is smaller than input for numofnames it will continue to ask question. This is another loop
        currentnum = currentnum + 1 # every time the question is asked it means that currentnum gets 1 added to it and will continue to ask untill it is the same as the input for numofnames
        name = str(input("Enter your name: ")) #Name asked to be entered in string
        name = name.upper() #This changes all letters to upper case no matter what so there is no error for upper and lower case or a bigger dictionary showing lower and upper case values.
        names.append(name)
```

Comment: Quick question. What does "error tapped" mean?

Comment: Like so that if someone puts in a number or something and I dont want them to then then the program will turn off and say you can only put in letters in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. The easiest way to describe what you're doing is to use the .isalpha attribute in an if statement.  First you will have to def your while loop
Like the following:

```
def Loop():
    name_input_complete = False
    while name_input_complete != True:
      string = input("Please input :")
      string = str(string)
      if string.isalpha(): 
        name_input_complete = True
      else:
        print("Please do not use numbers and spaces")
        Loop()
Loop()
```

Baisically you have to define the loop and then run it. The if statement(which is the part you should add to your loop) then checks if there is nothing other  than letters. If true, your done with error trapping and the loop is exited. The program continues outside the loop. If not then the while is repeated because the Loop() function is called again.

Comment: Ok so would I put that after names.append in the code? and what is the do something part how would I let it continue with the code if it was all in letters and if it wasnt end the code saying don not use spaces and numbers?

Comment: Im very sorry. I think i did something wrong. I will edit my answer so it shows the write code

Comment: Thank you so much it works great the only problem is the Loop() below else means that it loops the Please do not use spaces and numbers multiple times and does not give an oppurtunity to loop back and ask for the names again but that does not really matter for what I am going to achieve I just set it so that if they use spaces or numbers then the program will close. :)

Comment: np :) Im sure you've figured it out, but just in case i have an edited version  now that works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks very good to me. I dont see what input can the user put that could cause an error, since most data in python can be stringed AND names can be pretty much anything!. If you could comment exactly what error could be caused i might be able to help you

Comment: Like I dont want there to be numbers or spaces input only letters so is that .isalpha?